# Can't Add Network Printer but Can See Printer Queue

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, network-printer

I can view the network printer queue via clicking on hyperlink in a email: `\\someserver\someprinter`

[image]

In my past experience, that would add the printer to my printers but it is not this time.

I tried the add printer dialog and no luck there either.

[image]

How can I add this printer to my PC (Win10)?

**Update**

I think I figured it out.  Outlook is running on my machine via Citrix (via XenApp I'm guessing; so it is not really running on my machine) so when I click on the link in Outlook it's doing it on the server and I can see the printer queue.  When I try to enter that unc on my PC I don't have access to any of those network resources.

Comment: My pc is on domain A and the printer is on domain B.  There is no trust between the domains.  I suspect that is root of my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to "Connect" to your printer from the printer queue you have already accessed.

If you select the `Printer` tab on the top left of the queue, it should drop down with a number of options.

Of which you will choose **Connect**

[image]

This *should* add the printer to your local list of printers.

---

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think I tried that, but I'll try when I'm the client's site again, thanks

Comment: please see update

Comment: @spottedmahn Thanks for updating.  Glad you found out the problem!  Though me and Run5k may leave these answers for future reference (People with similar questions void of a Citrix environment)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my experience utilizing several corporate domains, you should be able to see the printers that are shared from the host server by navigating to the UNC path via a `Run` command:

1. On your Windows 10 machine, press [image: WinKey] + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. In the subsequent `Run` field, enter the UNC path to your host printer server:  **\\someserver\**
3. Within the ensuing window, select the printer you want to utilize by doing a right-click and choose `Connect...`

   [image: Printer Share]

Comment: I'm unable to access the host printer server: \\someserver

Comment: @spottedmahn , based upon what you said earlier, you should be able to access the host printer server.  If you can access the print queue the way that you described within your question, you should also be able to see the shared printers utilizing \\someserver\ and ensuring that you include the last "\" at the end.

Comment: I would have thought so too!  No,  I didn't include the last '\'.  I'll try that but I've never had to do that before when accessing an unc path.  I won't be on the client's site for another couple weeks but I'll try it then.

Comment: please see update

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That being said, if you had mentioned that you were utilizing Outlook remotely from the very beginning, I could have told you what the problem was on the very first day.  Regardless, I am glad to hear that you figured it out.